# Polygon consists of vertical adjacent towers of varying widths and heights. Find the largest area of a rectangle that fits inside this polygon

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out the largest possible area of a rectangle that can fit inside a polygon. This polygon consists of adjacent vertical towers each with their own widths and heights.

Basically I would be given the number of width height pairs for the towers and then the actual width and height values and would need to use this data to find the largest possible area of a`enter code here` rectangle to fit inside the polygon.

```js
import java.util.*;
public class LargestRectInHist {
 
 
 // The main function to find the maximum rectangular area under histogram
    
    static int getMaxArea(int heights[], int size)  
    { 
        // Create an empty stack. The stack holds indexes of heights[] array 
        
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>(); 
          
        int max_area = 0; // Stores the current highest area found in heights[]
        int top;  // Stores the current height at the top of the stack 
        int area=0; // Stores current area
       
        // Run through all bars of given histogram 
        int i = 0; 
        while (i < size) 
        { 
            // If this bar is higher than the bar on top of the stack, push it on the stack 
            if (stack.empty() || heights[stack.peek()] <= heights[i]) 
                stack.push(i++); 
            
       
            // If this bar is lower than the top of the stack, then calculate the area of the rectangle  
            // with the top of the stack as the smallest (or minimum height) bar. 'i' is  
            // 'right index' for the top and element before the top of the stack is 'left index' (or stack.peek())
            else
            { 
                top = stack.peek();  // store the top index 
                stack.pop();  // pop the top 
       
                // Calculate the area with heights[top] stack as smallest bar 
                
                
                
                if(stack.empty()) {
                 area = heights[top] * i;
                }else {
                 area = heights[top] * (i-stack.peek()-1);
                }
               
                
      // update max area, if needed 
                if (max_area < area) 
                    max_area = area; 
            } 
        } 
       
        // Now pop the remaining bars from stack and calculate area with every 
        // popped bar as the smallest bar 
        while (stack.empty() == false) 
        { 
            top = stack.peek(); 
            stack.pop(); 
            
            
            if(stack.empty()) {
             area = heights[top] * i;
            }else {
             area = heights[top] * (i-stack.peek()-1);
            }
           
           
            if (max_area < area) 
                max_area = area; 
        } 
       
        return max_area; 
  
    } 
    
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("Enter the size of your sequence:");
  int size = scan.nextInt();
  
  int heights[] = new int[size]; 
  System.out.println("Please enter the list of integers separated by a space");
  
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
         heights[i] = scan.nextInt();
       }
  
        System.out.println("Maximum area is " + getMaxArea(heights, size)); 

 }

}
```

I know how to solve this problem if we are just given heights for the towers and can assume all their widths are one(as the code above shows). The problem I'm having is incorporating the widths into my algorithm to find the max area. Any ideas on how my algorithm could be tweaked?

Comment: Are the rectangle vertical? Or they can place anywhere , any angle within towers?

Comment: Rectangle can be placed vertically or horizontally within towers.